# Don't understand this NullPointerException with ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, model, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I can't understand why I'm getting this NullPointerException.  I started with much different looking code (and improved to what you see) all in attempts of fixing the bug and I just can't figure out what's going on.

all help is hugely appreciated:

```
final JComboBox modelName = null;

//Model ComboBoxModel
final DefaultComboBoxModel termModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{
    "Choose One...", "Hypercom", "DejaVoo", "Nurit", "Verifone"});

...

// model drop-down      
    modelName.setModel(termModel);  //getting nullPointerException on this line

    modelName.addActionListener(this);              

    modelPanel.add(modelName);

...

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("Hypercom".equals(modelName.getSelectedItem())){
        termName.setModel(hSpecModel);    
    } else if ("Deja Voo".equals(modelName.getSelectedItem())){
        termName.setModel(dSpecModel);    
    } else if ("Nurit".equals(modelName.getSelectedItem())){
        termName.setModel(nSpecModel);
    } else if ("Verifone".equals(modelName.getSelectedItem())){
        termName.setModel(vSpecModel);
    } else {
        termName.setModel(slctAbove);
    }
}
```

Comment: Swing tag removed as the question has nothing to do with Swing and all to do with basic Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final JComboBox modelName = null; // !!!!!
```

You really shouldn't wonder why you get a NPE when you try to use this variable:

```
modelName.setModel(termModel);
```

Comment: learning as I go... I thought "modelName.setModel(termModel);" would overwrite the 'null'.

Comment: @WizardKnight: how would that (or anything) *overwrite* null? You must initialize a variable with a reference before you can use it, always.

Comment: Like I said, learning by doing.  This forum has actually been a huge amount of help.  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

`modelName` has not been initialized, so it doesn't point to an object.

You need something like

```
final JComboBox modelName = new JComboBox();
```

Comment: learning as I go... I thought "modelName.setModel(termModel);" would overwrite the 'null'.  Thanks so much, I think I've just been staring at this too long, that was really just punching everybody but me in the face :)